# How to compress multiple HDFS files into one

Tags: pyspark, hdfs, apache-zeppelin

I am working on a Zeppelin Cluster (w Spark), using `write.parquet()`, I end up with multiple Parquet files.
I was wondering, is it possible to merge them into one file? Or I have to use a `path="/folder/*"` every time?

Answer (score 1):

Use repartition():

```
df.repartition(1).write.parquet(path)
```

or, even better, coalesce()

```
df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(path)
```

Comment: thx, I will definitely try it out soon, but now or cluster is down :(